# Trying to display JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Using GridbagLayout, I'm trying to display a JTable. Here's my code (simplified). The jpanel code that I'll put is shown after a button click.

My Panel :

```
   optionspane = new JPanel();
        optionspane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        optionspane.setBounds(0, 0, myframe.getWidth(), myframe.getHeight());
```

My Panel's Children :

```
  GridBagConstraints dgbc=new GridBagConstraints();

    dgbc.gridx=0;
    dgbc.gridy=0;
    dgbc.weightx = 1.0;
    dgbc.weighty = 1.0;
    dgbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    dgbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    dgbc.insets=new Insets(5,10,10,5);
    datapane.add(ServiceInterface.eighthpanel(), dgbc);

    dgbc.gridx=0;
    dgbc.gridy=1;
    gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
    dgbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    dgbc.insets=new Insets(5,0,5,5);
    datapane.add(ServiceInterface.ninethpanel(), dgbc);
```

Here is the panel method that contains the JPanel :

```
  public static JPanel eighthpanel() throws IOException{
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
    pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

    JLabel datawelcome=new JLabel("Please Enter the QoS values'");
    datawelcome.setFont(new Font("Ubuntu", Font.BOLD, 16));


    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gbc.insets=new Insets(10,20,10,20);
    pane.add(datawelcome, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.weightx=1;
    gbc.weightx=1;
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gbc.insets=new Insets(10,20,10,20);
    //pane.add(new JScrollPane(displayJTable), gbc);
    pane.add(myscrol, gbc);

    return pane;
}
```

Here is how I fill my JTable (inside a button listener):

```
                mytableclass=new Mytable();
                displayJTable = new JTable(myModel);

    displayJTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(60);
    displayJTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(525,250));
                displayJTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
                displayJTable.setLocation(5,5);
                myscrol.add(displayJTable);
                myscrol.getViewport().setViewPosition(new Point(0,0));
                myscrol.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
                principalpane.setVisible(false);
                datapane.setVisible(true);
            }
        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. I added an other panel (default layout) and I added the scrollPane to this panel inside the button.actionlistener.
I think because of the Static characteristic of the gridbaglayout.

Comment: *"I think because of the Static characteristic of the gridbaglayout."* That reads like nonsense here.